# Python find max under constraint

Tags: python, algorithm, optimization, knapsack-problem

I'm learning python on my own and I'm unable to find the right solution for a specific problem:

I get x $.
I can buy a list of different items which each have a certain price (costs) and provide a particular gain (gain)
I want to get the maximum the gain for the x $.
There is only 1 of each item.
lets says :

```
dollars = 10
cost = [5, 4, 1, 10]
gain = [7, 6, 4, 12]
```

here => the max gain is 17

With a naïve solution, based on permutation, I managed to find a solution when the number of item is low.
but When the number of item grows, the time increase and the computer crashes.

Is there a typical algorithm to solve that kind of pb?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knapsack_problem

Comment: Sort descending each item by a ratio of gain/cost and keep adding items you can afford. For example, item 1 has ratio 7/5=1.4 and item 3 has ratio 4/1=4. So item 3 will be the first to add to cart

Comment: How is the max gain 17? With 10 dollars you could by 10 of the units that give a gain of 4 (index 2) and get a gain of 40.

Comment: Mureinik is correct. Nice catch.

Comment: @Mureinik: Pretty sure there's only supposed to be one of each item.

Comment: This question isn't really about [tag:python], it's about [tag:algorithms].

Comment: What does pb mean?

Comment: @mureinik. oups you are right. My bad.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You mentionned not being interested in the solution's code in one of your comments, so I'll only be explaining the algorithm. This problem is better known as the [0-1 knapsack problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knapsack_problem).
A typical approach to solving it is using [dynamic programming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_programming):

- let's define a value that we'll call `m(i, c)`, which is the max gain you can get by spending up to `c` $ and only buying items among the first `i` of your list.
  You've got:
- `m(0, c) = 0` (If you can't buy any item, you won't be getting any gain).
- `m(i, c) = m(i-1, c)` if `cost[i]>c` (if the new item is more than the cost limit, you won't be able to buy it anyways)
- `m(i, c) = max(m(i-1, c), m(i-1, c-cost[i]) + gain[i])` if `cost[i]<=c` (you're now able to buy item `i`. Either you do buy it, or you don't, and the best gain you can get out of it is the maximum of those two alternatives)

To get the best price, all you have to do is compute `m(len(cost), dollars)`. You can for example do so with a `for` loop where you'll compute `m(i, dollars)` for every `i` up to `len(cost)`, by filling a list of `m` values. To figure out which items were actually bought and not only the max gain, you'll have to save them in a separate list as you're filling out `m`.

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like a LeetCode problem, but I'll give you a decent answer (not the best, can definitely be optimized):

## Problem

Assuming you are trying to find the max amount of gain from any n items strung together without repeating any item, the following algorithm could work.

## Solution

You would take the highest ratio of the zipped cost and gain and remove that index from the zipped variable. Then, you'd redo the problem until you don't have enough money for any purchase:

#### Code:

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python3
dollars = 10
cost = [5, 4, 1, 10]
gain = [7, 6, 4, 12]

result_gain = 0

zipped = [i for i in zip(cost, gain)]
largestgain = []

# create ratio of cost to gain and pick from the smallest to the largest
ratios = []
for x in zipped:
    # divide the gain by the cost
    ratios.append(x[1]/x[0])

# create a largest variable to grab the largest ratio from a for loop for every updated index
largest = 0
for x in range(0, len(zipped)):
    for index, ratio in enumerate(ratios):
        if index == 0:
            largest = ratio
        else:
            if ratio > largest:
                largest = ratio # let largest be the new largest ratio

    # get the index of the largest ratio
    largest = ratios.index(largest)
    print(largest)

    # append the largest gain to a list of what should be added up later
    largestgain.append(zipped[largest])

    # check if dollars, when subtracted from the first index, yield less than 0
    if dollars - zipped[largest][0] < 0:
        break
    # if not, subtract dollars from total and update resulted gain
    else:
        dollars = dollars - zipped[largest][0]
        result_gain = result_gain + zipped[largest][1]

    # delete the largest zipped variable in order to redo this process
    del zipped[largest]
    # delete the largest ratio as well in order to redo this process
    del ratios[largest]

    # print the list that would yield you the largest ratios in order from largest to smallest, but in the form of a zipped list
    print(largestgain)

# The max amount of gain earned
print(result_gain)
```

#### Explanation:

I added the shebang so that you can test it yourself, but it should work perfectly. I've commented my code so that you can read the algorithm's process. Test it with larger lists if you want to.

Be aware that there aren't exception checkers for the lengths of cost and gain lists, so if the cost list is larger than the gain list, it will divide a buffer that doesn't exist and an exception will be thrown.

If this algorithm is too slow, feel free to check this [resource](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knapsack_problem) for other knapsack algorithm solutions. This one is quite elegant, but others, not so much.

### EDIT:

This is a very greedy algorithm and doesn't work for all values, as noted by a commenter. Refer to theory for better explanations.

Comment: Let it be noted that this greedy algorithm does not always return the optimal solution - a simple counter-example would be `dollars=3`, `cost=[5,20,10]` and `gain=[50,140,60]`. This algorithm then returns 190 instead of 200.